# How to create a pop-up confirmation message button href in Flask Jinja

Tags: javascript, flask, popup, message, confirmation

I have a Flask application and I want to create a button with a pop-up confirmation message before executing an action. Currently, the button is created using an anchor tag and a URL to call a Flask function with the HTTP DELETE method. However, I want to refactor the code to use just Flask functions and JavaScript to create the pop-up confirmation message.

In the current implementation, the anchor tag is used to call a Flask function with the HTTP DELETE method, which deletes the product with the given ID. The code for the anchor tag looks like this:

Delete

To create a pop-up confirmation message before deleting the product, I want to use JavaScript to create a confirm window. I have implemented the JavaScript code to create a confirm window, but I'm not sure how to integrate it with the Flask function to execute the delete action.

Here's the JavaScript code for creating a confirm window:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  let text;
  if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
    text = "You pressed OK!";
  } else {
    text = "You canceled!";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

</script>
```

I want to refactor the code to use just Flask functions and create a pop-up confirmation message before calling the delete function. Can someone help me integrate the JavaScript code with the Flask function to create the desired behavior?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. We appreciate your inquiry, but in order to assist you effectively, we kindly request that you provide more specific details or clarify your problem. As it stands, your query is a bit ambiguous, making it difficult for us to determine exactly what you're seeking assistance with. Please provide additional information so that we can better understand your needs and provide you with a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution

```
<a href="{{ url_for('productos.delete', id=producto.codprod) }}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
```

and the button style

option 1

```
<a
  href="{{ url_for('productos.delete', id=producto.codprod) }}"
  onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"
  type="button"
  style="text-decoration: none;
    min-width: 100px; 
    max-height: 30px; 
    background-color: #224a64; 
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center; 
    border-radius: 6px; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    right: 0px;
  "
  >Eliminar
  </a>
```

option 2

```
<a href="{{ url_for('productos.delete', id=producto.codprod) }}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></a>
```

Comment: if I get support I can document better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).